# Flutter : PageController.page cannot be accessed before a PageView is built with it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

How to solve the exception:

> Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 179 pos 7: 'positions.isNotEmpty':
> PageController.page cannot be accessed before a PageView is built with
> it.

Note: I used it in two screens and when I switch between screens, it shows the above exception.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _animateSlider());
}

void _animateSlider() {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then(
    (_) {
      int nextPage = _controller.page.round() + 1;

      if (nextPage == widget.slide.length) {
        nextPage = 0;
      }

      _controller
          .animateToPage(nextPage,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear)
          .then(
            (_) => _animateSlider(),
          );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: can you show me your entire code in which you are using the pageViewController?

Answer (score 24):

I think you can just use a Listener like this:

```
int _currentPage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _currentPage = 0;
    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _currentPage = _controller.page.toInt();
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 18):

I don't have enough information to see exactly where your problem is, but I just encountered a similar issue where I wanted to group a PageView and labels in the same widget and I wanted to mark active the current slide and the label so I was needing to access `controler.page` in order to do that. Here is my fix :

#### Fix for accessing page index before `PageView` widget is built using `FutureBuilder` widget

```dart
class Carousel extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController controller;

  Carousel({this.controller});

  /// Used to trigger an event when the widget has been built
  Future<bool> initializeController() {
    Completer<bool> completer = new Completer<bool>();

    /// Callback called after widget has been fully built
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      completer.complete(true);
    });

    return completer.future;
  } // /initializeController()

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        // **** FIX **** //
        FutureBuilder(
          future: initializeController(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snap) {
            if (!snap.hasData) {
              // Just return a placeholder widget, here it's nothing but you have to return something to avoid errors
              return SizedBox();
            }

            // Then, if the PageView is built, we return the labels buttons
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                CustomLabelButton(
                  child: Text('Label 1'),
                  isActive: controller.page.round() == 0,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                CustomLabelButton(
                  child: Text('Label 2'),
                  isActive: controller.page.round() == 1,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                CustomLabelButton(
                  child: Text('Label 3'),
                  isActive: controller.page.round() == 2,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
        // **** /FIX **** //
        PageView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          controller: controller,
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomPage(),
            CustomPage(),
            CustomPage(),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

#### Fix if you need the index directly in the PageView children

You can use a stateful widget instead :

```dart
class Carousel extends StatefulWidget {
  Carousel();

  @override
  _HomeHorizontalCarouselState createState() => _CarouselState();
}

class _CarouselState extends State<Carousel> {
  final PageController controller = PageController();
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    /// Attach a listener which will update the state and refresh the page index
    controller.addListener(() {
      if (controller.page.round() != currentIndex) {
        setState(() {
          currentIndex = controller.page.round();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
           Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                CustomLabelButton(
                  child: Text('Label 1'),
                  isActive: currentIndex == 0,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                CustomLabelButton(
                  child: Text('Label 2'),
                  isActive: currentIndex == 1,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                CustomLabelButton(
                  child: Text('Label 3'),
                  isActive: currentIndex == 2,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ]
        ),
        PageView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          controller: controller,
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomPage(isActive: currentIndex == 0),
            CustomPage(isActive: currentIndex == 1),
            CustomPage(isActive: currentIndex == 2),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This means that you are trying to access `PageController.page` (It could be you or by a third party package like Page Indicator), however, at that time, Flutter hasn't yet rendered the `PageView` widget referencing the controller.

## Best Solution: Use `FutureBuilder` with `Future.value`

Here we just wrap the code using the `page` property on the `pageController` into a future builder, such that it is rendered little after the `PageView` has been rendered.

We use `Future.value(true)` which will cause the Future to complete immediately but still wait enough for the next frame to complete successfully, so `PageView` will be already built before we reference it.

```
class Carousel extends StatelessWidget {

  final PageController controller;

  Carousel({this.controller});

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[

        FutureBuilder(
          future: Future.value(true),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snap) {
            
            //If we do not have data as we wait for the future to complete,
            //show any widget, eg. empty Container
            if (!snap.hasData) {
             return Container();
            }

            //Otherwise the future completed, so we can now safely use the controller.page
            return Text(controller.controller.page.round().toString);
          },
        ),

        //This PageView will be built immediately before the widget above it, thanks to
        // the FutureBuilder used above, so whenever the widget above is rendered, it will
        //already use a controller with a built `PageView`        

        PageView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          controller: controller,
          children: <Widget>[
           AnyWidgetOne(),
           AnyWidgetTwo()
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

### Alternatively

Alternatively, you could still use a `FutureBuilder` with a future that completes in `addPostFrameCallback` in `initState` lifehook as it also will complete the future after the current frame is rendered, which will have the same effect as the above solution. But **I would highly recommend the first solution** as it is straight-forward

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
     //Future will be completed here 
     // e.g completer.complete(true);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but it worked for me:

instead of:

```dart
int nextPage = _controller.page.round() + 1;
```

you can do:

```dart
late int nextPage = _controller.page.round() + 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello you can simply type:

```
pageController.hasClients ? 
   pageController.page == 0 ? Text("Page 1") : Text("Page 2")
 : Text("Initialization")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).